# clickonce install fail - URLDownloadToCacheFile HRESULT '-2146697191'

Tags: clickonce

trying to run the setup.exe to install

from the install.log file, here is the error:

```
Launching Application.
URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697191'
Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://galantha.net/appPublishGalanthasEncryptedNotes/GalsPassHolder.application'.
```

-2146697191 = 0x800C0019

Which leads to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775145(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
INET_E_INVALID_CERTIFICATE 0x800C0019   
The SSL certificate is invalid.
```

And then I hit a wall.  I cannot figure out why it feels the certificate is invalid?

the deployment is hosted here:
https://galantha.net/appPublishGalanthasEncryptedNotes/publish.htm
and the certificate checks out fine:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://galantha.net/appPublishGalanthasEncryptedNotes/publish.htm

I can also see that:
https://galantha.net/appPublishGalanthasEncryptedNotes/GalsPassHolder.application
will download fine, provided the user ignores the warning about .application.  Nothing about an ssl error.

Any help would be appreciated.